# AWS Java SDK v2.10: QuickSightClient throws SdkClientException When Delete is Successful

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, aws-java-sdk-2.x

`quickSightClient.deleteUser(deleteUserRequest)` throws a null pointer exception because it fails to marshall the 204 No Content response, which AWS Quicksight returns after successfully deleting a user.

**My Questions:**

1. Is there a better way to handle or avoid this problem than using a try/catch to swallow the error (see below)?
2. <s>Should I report this as an bug in their GitHub project?</s> I reported this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1570).

**My Code:**

```
private void deleteQuickSightUser() {
    String awsAccountId = "..."
    String roleName = "cc-embedding_quicksight_dashboard_role"
    String email = "person@company.com"
    String namespace = "default"
    String roleArn = "arn:aws:iam::$awsAccountId:role/$roleName"

    QuickSightClient quickSightClient = QuickSightClient.create()

    User user = quickSightClient.listUsers(ListUsersRequest.builder()
        .awsAccountId(awsAccountId)
        .namespace(namespace)
        .build()
    ).userList().find { it.email() == email }

    if (user) {
        log.error("found the $email user with username: $user.userName")
        DeleteUserRequest deleteUserRequest = DeleteUserRequest.builder()
            .awsAccountId(awsAccountId)
            .namespace(namespace)
            .userName(user.userName)
            .build()

        try {

            /* *** THE FOLLOWING LINE THROWS THE EXCEPTION *** */
            quickSightClient.deleteUser(deleteUserRequest)

        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            log.error(e.message)
        }

        log.error("deleted user $user.email")
    }
}
```

**The Exception**

```
2020-01-03 09:53:36.168 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /
Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (null). Response Code: 204, Response Text: No Content
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:97)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleSuccessResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:100)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:70)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:58)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:41)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:73)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:77)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:39)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.doExecute(RetryableStage.java:113)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.execute(RetryableStage.java:86)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:62)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:57)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:37)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:240)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:96)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:120)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:73)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:44)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.quicksight.DefaultQuickSightClient.deleteUser(DefaultQuickSightClient.java:1341)
    at grails4test.ApplicationController.deleteUser(ApplicationController.groovy:85)
    at grails4test.ApplicationController.doStuff(ApplicationController.groovy:44)
    at grails4test.ApplicationController.index(ApplicationController.groovy:23)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.io.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:66)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.ensureLoaded(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:522)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.detectEncoding(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.constructParser(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:246)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory._createParser(JsonFactory.java:1315)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:820)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.dom.JsonDomParser.parse(JsonDomParser.java:39)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.unmarshall.JsonProtocolUnmarshaller.unmarshall(JsonProtocolUnmarshaller.java:167)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.unmarshall.JsonResponseHandler.handle(JsonResponseHandler.java:79)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.unmarshall.JsonResponseHandler.handle(JsonResponseHandler.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.unmarshall.AwsJsonResponseHandler.handle(AwsJsonResponseHandler.java:43)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler$Crc32ValidationResponseHandler.handle(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:88)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseClientHandler.lambda$interceptorCalling$2(BaseClientHandler.java:151)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.AttachHttpMetadataResponseHandler.handle(AttachHttpMetadataResponseHandler.java:40)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.AttachHttpMetadataResponseHandler.handle(AttachHttpMetadataResponseHandler.java:28)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleSuccessResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:89)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use try/catch for now and report this as a bug. What does the stack trace look like?